# How to install Tensorflow in Kali Linux (Raspberry Pi 4 ARM Images)?

Tags: tensorflow, arm, raspberry-pi4, kali-linux

[image]I tried with
`sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
and then

`pip3 install tensorflow Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from version: none). Error: No matching distribution found for tensorflow.`

then I am unable to install so I tried to rename it with CP34 instead of CP35 for supported installation but failed again.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of TensorFlow can be installed from pre-built binaries on a Raspberry Pi using Python’s pip package system. To install TensorFlow on a Raspberry Pi run the following commands.

```
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install tensorflow
```

TensorFlow also runs fine in the Google Colaboratory web app without installing any software on your local device. Google Colaboratory makes it easy for a novice TensorFlow user to learn how to program with TensorFlow because all the software you need to start coding is already installed and ready to use on Google's servers.